# Should you use scriptable objects when making items?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make some test items for my item pick up system and wanted to know if scriptable objects are necessary when making items or if it's just a situaional thing? Since I don't have a lot of items and they're all doing basic things doing scriptable objects seems a bit overkill(?)

Here's the code I currently use should I be using an SO approach instead or are is it fine to continue like this?

```cs
public class BaseItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    Outline outline;

    void Awake()
    {
        // Adds the outline script which outlines the item
        // when the camera is looking at it
        outline = gameObject.AddComponent<Outline>();
        rigidBody = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public virtual void Use()
    {
        Debug.Log("Using Item");
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Flashlight : BaseItem
{
    GameObject light;

    public override void Use()
    {
        light.SetActive(!light.activeSelf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BaseItem currently inherits from MonoBehavior, which has even more functionality than ScriptableObject. If you are asking if you should make an additional class that inherits from ScriptableObject, it depends on if you need that for some purpose. Don't introduce new functionality unless it has some purpose.